# rewriting a piecewise equation as a non-piecewsie equation: odd and even

Tags: functions

I would like to write the equation,
$$I=\begin{cases} 
      k & N \text{ even} \\
      0 & N \text{ odd}
   \end{cases}$$
as a function of $N$ in a non-piecewise format.

Any guidance/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How about $I=\frac{k}{2}(1+(-1)^{N})$?

Comment: If you need to smoothly interpolate between the reals, $I=k\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi N}{2}\right)$ should work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I = \frac{k\left(1+(-1)^N\right)}{2} 
$$